# Can Perl DBI connect to Redbrick?

Tags: perl, dbi, redbrick

Is there a way for DBI to connect to a RedBrick database?  I don't see a driver anywhere, and there is very little discussion of this.

Comment: You should ask IBM. After all, it has a price tag of about $30,000 - $60,000 depending on version (see https://www-112.ibm.com/software/howtobuy/buyingtools/paexpress/Express?P0=E1&part_number=D6DAGLL,D6DAPLL&catalogLocale=en_US&Locale=en_US&country=USA&PT=html )

Comment: Ideally, yes.  However, the right hand does not always know what the left hand is doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RedBrick [supports ODBC](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rbhelp/v6r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.redbrick.doc6.3/ciacg/ciacg19.htm), so you should be able to use the [DBI ODBC driver](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD::ODBC).

Comment: Hmm, good point.  I guess I was focused on a dedicated driver but I suppose a generic one will work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not familiar with or has even heard of RedBrick before, as long as it "fits" the DBI API, you should be able to write your own driver for it.

Take a look at [DBI::DBD](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI::DBD) on how to do that.